# How can I move an obj inside a canvas using touch event?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hello everybody I've just trying to understands how this does it work
I have a basic canvas base just in javascript and I would like to move it using touch event

I'm not sure about this but Can I use the **drag event** ?

Do I need to use a loop function ?

How can I trigger that blue  cube ?

I know there are lot of javascript engine in fact i'm using phaser but I would like to undertand this

Thank you

```js
var canvas, cx, width, height;

var cube = {
    x: 80,
    y: 100,
    update: function () {

    },
    draw: function (ctx) {
        ctx.save();

        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.fillRect(100, 410, 50, 50);

        ctx.restore();
    }
};


function onpress(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var whichArt = e.target;
    var touch = e.touches[0];

    var moveOffsetX = whichArt.offsetLeft - touch.pageX;
    var moveOffsetY = whichArt.offsetTop - touch.pageY;

    whichArt.addEventListener('touchmove', function () {
        var positionX = touch.pageX + moveOffsetX;
        var positionY = touch.pageY + moveOffsetY;

        cube.x = positionX;
        cube.y = positionY;

        console.log(cube.x);
    }, false);
}

function main() {
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;

    if (width >= 500) {
        width = 320;
        height = 480;
        canvas.style.border = "1px solid #000";
    }

    document.addEventListener("touchstart", onpress);
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    run();
}


function run() {
    var loop = function () {
        update();
        render();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
}

function update() {

}

function render() {

    cube.draw(ctx);
}

main();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/marcogomesr/sxbo3r83/

Comment: There is no `drag` event in JS.

Comment: look at this --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragstart

Comment: Here's info on which browsers support this. http://caniuse.com/#feat=dragndrop Also, this won't help you in canvas since you'd be dragging the whole canvas element.

Answer (score 2):

The canvas is only a passive drawing surface : You have to handle the drag by yourself.
Below a short example :
draggables object have to implement `isPointInside`, and to be added to the list of draggables object.
I used a dragData object that stores the list of draggables object, the currently dragged object, maybe you'll want to store the start/current point of the drag, and handle a drag-offset so the user holds the object right on the point where he/she started dragging.

http://jsfiddle.net/3ksvn4y0/3/

```
var canvas, cx, width, height;
var canvasRect;

var cube1, cube2;

var dragData = {
    draggables: [],
    start: {        x: 0,        y: 0
    },
    current: {      x: 0,        y: 0
    },
    target: null
};

function Cube(x,y,w,h, color) {
  this.x=x; this.y=y; this.w=w; this.h = h;
  this.color = color;
}

Cube.prototype = {
    update: function () {

    },
    draw: function (ctx) {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    },
    isPointInside: function (x, y) {
        return (x >= this.x) && (x < this.x + this.w) && (y > this.y) && (y < this.y + this.h);
    }
};

var pointerCoords = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    update: function (e) {
        var coords = e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e;
        this.x = coords.pageX - canvasRect.left;
        this.y = coords.pageY - canvasRect.top;
    }
};


function onStart(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    pointerCoords.update(e);
    // look if we start the touch within a draggable object
    var target = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < dragData.draggables.length; i++) {
        var draggable = dragData.draggables[i];
        if (draggable.isPointInside(pointerCoords.x, pointerCoords.y)) {
            target = draggable;
            break;
        }
    }
    dragData.target = target;
}

function onMove(e) {
    pointerCoords.update(e);
    var target = dragData.target;
    if (!target) return;
    target.x = pointerCoords.x;
    target.y = pointerCoords.y;
}

function onStop(e) {
    pointerCoords.update(e);
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!dragData.target) return;
    onMove(e);
    dragData.target = null;
}

function main() {
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;

    if (width >= 500) {
        width = 320;
        height = 480;
        canvas.style.border = "1px solid #000";
    }

    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    canvasRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", onStart);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', onMove);
    canvas.addEventListener("touchstop", onStop);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", onStart);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMove);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", onStop);

    cube1 = new Cube(100, 80, 30, 30, 'blue');
    cube2 = new Cube(150, 160, 20, 20, 'red');
    dragData.draggables.push(cube1, cube2);
    run();
}


function run() {
    var loop = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        update();
        render();
    }
    loop();
}

function update() {

}

function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    cube1.draw(ctx);
    cube2.draw(ctx);
}

main();
```